# Stuck on next letter generator -- Python 3

Tags: python, if-statement, python-3.x, chr, ord

Currently, I am taking some computer science lessons online.  I have been issued the task of writing a program that, upon a valid input, will print the next letter in the alphabet.  Here is my code:

```
char = input()
ordchar = ord(char)
nextletter = ordchar + 1
nextletter = chr(nextletter)

if nextletter == ("["):
    print("A")

if nextletter == ("{"):
    print("a")

if nextletter!=("[","{"):
    print(nextletter)
```

Now, I do see the problem with the code, though I don't know how to rectify it.  Basically, on the second to last line of code, I want it to essentially say "if nextletter does not equal { or [ print nextletter".

Answer (score 5):

```
if nextletter not in ["[", "{"]:
    print(nextletter)
```

Comment: downvoter: Please explain how my answer is wrong/different than the other answers? What?

Comment: @cIph3r: No, Ingbar is using a *list*, not a list comprehension. There is not much difference between using a tuple and a list here.

Comment: @cIph3r You are correct that generators are faster than list-comprehension when storing the results doesn't matter, but in this case, you are just totally confused, see other responses.

Comment: This is fine, though I think @MartijnPieters' answer using `not in` against a string is a slightly more Pythonic way of doing this -- it's also a bit more readable, as there's only 2 characters of punctuation instead of 7.

Answer (score 5):

You do not need to test for those characters *at all*. In the code before it you make sure that `nextletter` is *never* going to be either `[` or `{`, if you just assign a different letter to `nextletter` there:

```
if nextletter == "[":
    nextletter = "A"
elif nextletter == "{":
    nextletter = 'a'
```

If you still need to make such a test, use the [`not in` operator](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#not-in):

```
if nextletter not in '[{':
```

`not in` returns `True` if the left-hand operand is not present in the sequence on the right. I used a string with two characters in my example, which counts as a sequence:

```
>>> '[' in '[{'
True
>>> '0' in '[{':
False
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `not in` membership operator:

```
if nextletter not in ("[","{"):
    print(nextletter)
```

Also note that, you can avoid the third test if you used `if-elif` construct rather than individual `if's`. That way, you can just put the 3rd part in an `else` block.

Comment: Wow, that was quick.  Thanks, you were a real help.

Answer (score 0):

While the other answers are correct, the right way of doing what you want is using `elif`and `else`:

```
if nextletter == ("[") :
    print("A")
elif nextletter == ("{") :
    print("a")
else :
    print(nextletter)
```

Comment: I was literally two characters away from that in an earlier version of the program, but I forgot to use elif.  Can't blame me, I've only been using Python for 5 days.

Comment: @cIph3r Because you are not doing a redundant check: if you reach the `else` then `nextletter` cannot be either `[` or `{`.

Comment: ok, but the runtime will be close to unmeasurable faster.
Also the code is longer and looks more complex, making the code less readable ;)

Comment: @cIph3r It is not longer, takes the exact same number of lines as the OP's code. It's biggest advantage is not execution speed, but minimizing the chances for errors and maintainability: if tomorrow you decide to check for `?` instead of `[`, you only need to edit one line, not two. And if you find using `else if` statements hurts readability, then you need to read more code.

Comment: @cIph3r The most voted answer still requires handling the `[` and `{` cases separately, which means four more lines.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are asking if nextletter is not equal to the tuple of `("[","{")`. You wanted to ask if it is not equal to either "[" or "{". Therefore, you must ask,
`if nextletter != "[" and nextletter != "{"`
This will check if it is neither "[" nor "{". Hope this helps

Comment: And that can be shortened to any one of the answers by [Martijn](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14922929/1561176), [Rohit](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14922919/1561176) or [Myself](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14922921/1561176)